# find hashtag in url and append to last in that url using php

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need solution to find hashtag in url and append to last in that url using php.

> **Old URL :** http://www.example.com?q=123123#anchor1?name=shreyas&city=surat
>
> **New URL :** http://www.example.com?q=123123&name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

Comment: `window.location.search = window.location.search + window.location.hash;`

Comment: @adeneo `window.location.hash` will contain the query string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com#anchor1?name=shreyas&city=surat';
var hash = /#[^?]+/.exec(url)[0];
url = url.replace(hash, '') + hash;
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkHcV/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

**HTML :**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com#anchor1?name=shreyas&city=surat">My Url</a>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var url= $("a").attr("href");
//get the subString matching that pattern "#...?"
var subUrl = url.match("\#[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*");
// removes the subString that matches the pattern "#...?"
url= url.replace(/\#[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*/, '');
//final url
url= url+ subUrl;
//updating it
$("a").attr("href", url);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/xLg3X/)